# Tkinter Spinbox Widget

Tags: python, set, widget, tkinter

How do I do a command that will set the default value on a Tkinter spinbox widget? 
For some reason they didn't give it the attribute **.set()**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for the "insert" command?

The following example sets the value to 2:

```
Tkinter.Spinbox(values=(1,2,3,4))
sb.delete(0,"end")
sb.insert(0,2)
```